# What is the difference between nth-child() and eq()

Tags: css, ruby, xpath, nokogiri

I gone through the link [`Difference between nth-child() and eq()`](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/difference-between-nth-child-and-eq). Which says that -

> it is very straight forward. nth-child is 1 indexed while eq is 0 indexed. nth-child is based on the current elements parent, while .eq is based off of the index of the current element relative to the selected elements. they are two completely different methods with two completely different purposes.

Now to get the things properly I wrote the below code:

```
doc =  Nokogiri::HTML::Document.parse(<<-eohtml)
<html>
<head>
<style>
div { float:left; }
span { color:blue; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div>
      <p>div1 p1</p>
      <p>div1 p2</p>
      <p>div1 p3</p>
      <p>div1 p4</p>
</div>
<div>
      <p>div2 p1</p>
      <p>div2 p2</p>
      <p>div2 p3</p>
      <p>div2 p4</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
eohtml

p doc.css("div p:eq(2)").map { |e| e.text }
p doc.css("div p:nth-child(2)").map { |e| e.text }
# >> ["div1 p2", "div2 p2"] Expected ["div1 p3", "div2 p3"]
# >> ["div1 p2", "div2 p2"]
```

Can any on help me to understand where I did wrong? Actually with this output I don't understand the difference between these 2 css selectors.

***EDIT***

I am not good with `XPATH` concept. I tried to convert the `CSS rules` to `XPATH` as below:

```
Nokogiri::CSS.xpath_for("div p:eq(2)")
Nokogiri::CSS.xpath_for("div p:nth-child(2)")
# >> ["//div//p[position() = 2]"]
# >> ["//div//*[position() = 2 and self::p]"]
```

Can anyone help me by explain the `xpath` expression, hope then it will make sense to me ?

Comment: You're reading jQuery documentation for perspective on Nokogiri?

Comment: @alex No I was reading *Jquery css selectors*, as Nokogiri supports that. I would use those in my coding, so before doing coding I am going through the CSS rules.

Comment: :eq is not a standard CSS selector. It's a extension in jQuery and Nokogiri. And they are different. In jQuery, only the 3rd `p` in the first div will be selected. However, in Nokogiri, it's seems to be an alias of `nth-child`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The first one:

```
Nokogiri::CSS.xpath_for("div p:eq(2)")
# >> ["//div//p[position() = 2]"]
```

This is also known as `//div//p[2]` and it means "return the second `p` elements" no matter whether they have other sibling elements.

The second one:

```
Nokogiri::CSS.xpath_for("div p:nth-child(2)")
# >> ["//div//*[position() = 2 and self::p]"]
```

This means "find all elements in the second position, and return them ONLY if they *also* happen to be a `p`.

**Example**

Consider the following HTML:

```
<html>
<body>
    <div>
        <p>Div1p1</p>
        <i>Div1i1</i>
        <p>Div1p2</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>Div2p1</p>
        <p>Div2p2</p>
        <p>Div2p3</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The output of `//p[2]` will be:

```
<p>Div1p2</p>
<p>Div2p2</p>
```

because "Div1p2" is the second `p` in the first `div`, and "Div2p2" is the second `p` in the second `div`.

The output of `//*[position()=2 and self::p]` will be:

```
<p>Div2p2</p>
```

because the second element of the first div is an `i`, not a `p`. But the second element of the second div also happens to be a `p` so it matches.

Comment: Excellent explanation of the `xpath` part. *+1* to you. I have very few knowledge with `xpath`. Could you refer me a good tutorial of `xpath` for beginners?

Comment: @RubyLovely I'm pretty sure I learned it from an O'Reilly book, but it was many years ago. I hear the XPath 1.0 tutorial and reference at [ZVON.org](http://zvon.org/comp/m/xpath.html) is pretty good.